# Symfony подключить js/

Tags: symfony, twig

Нужно подключить js и css файлы в шаблоне twig в symfony. Использую, как в документации

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Unexpected "javascripts" tag (expecting closing tag for the "block" tag defined near line 6) in main.html.twig
```

с css аналогичная ошибка.

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

`Unknown "stylesheets" tag in main.html.twig at line 5.`
 Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет, как исправить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем разобрался. В Symfony начиная с 2.8 Assetic нет по умолчанию, из-за его отсутствия и была эта ошибка. Установить можно по документации 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html